# Most efficient way to read the last line (lastindex) of listbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, performance, listbox

```
I am looking for the most efficient way to read the last line of listbox in visual basic
```

For example, if my listbox contains the following:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

Then the output whenever I clicked the button should be the `last line` which is **g**

I am using this code to get the job done, however I am looking for the most effiicient and effective way for this when I have thousands or even hundred thousands of item in listbox.

```
    Dim lastline As Integer = (lstData.Items.Count - 1)
    lstData.Text = lstData.Items(lastline).ToString
    events_class.events_function(lastline)
```

Comment: The flaw in the code you've provided is when the ListBox has no items.  You would then be trying to get an item from the ListBox at index -1.  Other than that, I don't see how your code gets anymore efficient.

Comment: It's a list box - reading lines from a list box would be orders of magnitude more efficient than the UI needs to render it. It's a completely unnecessary optimisation. Even with thousands of elements...

Answer (score 0):

This will get a total number of contents in your list box.

```
'This code will set the selected index of the item to the last item in
'the list, regardless of how many items are in it.
 If ListBox1.Items.Count > 0 Then _
                ListBox1.SelectedIndex = ListBox.Items.Count - 1
```

Hope this will help you..
Regards